# Java ProcessBuilder ImageMagic convert command

Tags: java, imagemagick

I'm trying to run convert command from image magic, and for both cases this command does not work.

Here is the code I use:

```
String command = String.format("convert \"%s\" -rotate %s \"%s\"", inputFileString, "" + degrees, outputFileString);
log.info(command);

ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("convert", inputFileString, "-rotate " + degrees, outputFileString);
Process p = pb.start();
```

The first case i have I get the following output, and this is the same response I get when I use the im4java library. That is why I decided to use the commands first.

```
2016-06-11 22:19:09 INFO - convert "C:\photo-gallery\photo-gallery-ui\portfolios\admin\test4\v\1465675527119.jpg" -rotate 90.0 "C:\photo-gallery\photo-gallery-ui\portfolios\admin\test4\v\1465676349249.jpg"
2016-06-11 22:19:09 ERROR - Invalid Parameter - -rotate
```

The second case is when I have space in my file:

```
2016-06-11 22:23:00 INFO - convert "C:\photo-gallery\photo-gallery-ui\portfolios\admin\Mare i Marko\Marko[2]\12717488_1578649372458773_429110010804118179_n.jpg" -rotate 90.0 "C:\photo-gallery\photo-gallery-ui\portfolios\admin\Mare i Marko\Marko[2]\1465676580556.jpg"
2016-06-11 22:23:00 ERROR - Invalid Parameter - i
```

Why do I get invalida parameters? I did the info output in the log, and when I copy/paste this into command line, command passes in both cases. Why can't I use this command as I did the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is actually that calling `convert` will result in calling [the Windows `convert` utility](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/windows/#convert_issue). This utility does not have a `-rotate` option, which explains your error. In your case, you need to spawn a new process with `cmd.exe /C` so that the environment variable `PATH`, containing the path to the ImageMagick `convert` executable, is set.

The second point to consider is that each parameter should be set as a separate command of the `ProcessBuilder`. Passing `"-rotate 90"` as a single command won't work, you need to pass two commands: `"-rotate"` and `"90"`.

As such, the following construction of `ProcessBuilder` will work as intended:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/C", "convert", inputFileString, "-rotate", degrees, outputFileString);
```

If `degrees` is not a `String` but an `int` for example, you can still convert it to one with [`String.valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf-int-).

Comment: Thank you. I would have never guessed this calls for another application. This complicates things as I need to develop for unix environment on windows platform. Tried my code on debian, it works without any changes.

Comment: @user1925253 Yes, it is a bit of a pain. Another possibility that I'm thinking of is to use the full path to the imagemagick utility and use that.